# How to Combine Two Methods Into One

Tags: php, methods, hook

I'm working on a plugin class that includes both events, and hooks for an MVC PHP application.

Events are designed to be called, as imagined, on state changes, mostly in the Models as that's where the data changes, there a few sprinkled into the controllers as well for login, logout etc.

I want the hooks to be available to methods throughout the app for the most part, there will be a few exceptions.

I've built out the storage and registration of hooks, they are then pushed to my registry class so they're available app wide.

The hooks are stored like so:

```
Array
 (
  [admin_controller] => Array // type of hook
   (
     [0] => Array
      (
        [class] => \Admin\Controller\Tool\Test // class to hook
        [method] => index // method to hook
        [callback] => /Plugin/Test/Hooks/Controller/exampleHook // callback to run
        [arguments] => Array  // any arguments required
          (
            [heading_title] => Example Test Page
            [item_title] => Item title
           )
       )
    )
)
```

But now I'm not sure how to make the two methods into one. I don't want the hook to override the original method, just add to it.

I also don't want to have to go and listen for it in each method across the 1700 file app either :P

Is there a way to get the contents of a given method, and pass it to an anonymous function to build the two into one, or should I reflect it?

What's the best technique to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

For any interested, I used a closure to pass the callback to the existing method as an argument.

```
$callable = false;
$hook_key = str_replace('\\', '', strtolower($prefix)) . '_controller';

if (array_key_exists($hook_key, $hooks)):
    foreach($hooks[$hook_key] as $hook):
        if ($hook['class'] === $class && $hook['method'] === $this->method):

            $mthd = basename($hook['callback']);
            $cls  = rtrim(str_replace($mthd, '', $hook['callback']), '/');

            $callback = array(
                'class'  => str_replace('/', '\\', $cls),
                'method' => $mthd,
                'args'   => $hook['arguments']
            );

            $callable = function () use ($callback) {
                $hook = new $callback['class'];
                if (is_callable(array($hook, $callback['method']))):
                    return call_user_func_array(array($hook, $callback['method']), $callback['args']);
                endif;
            };

        endif;

        if ($callable):
            $this->args[] = $callable();
        endif;
    endforeach;
endif;
```

The only remaining issue is that the hook arguments array loses it's keys when it's executed.

When dumping `func_get_args()` on the callback above it produces:

```
array (size=2)
  0 => string 'Example Test Page' (length=17)
  1 => string 'Item title' (length=10)
```

If I wrap `'args' => $hook['arguments']` in an array `'args' => array($hook['arguments'])` then the keys are preserved, but the array is nested.

```
array (size=1)
  0 => 
    array (size=2)
      'heading_title' => string 'Example Test Page' (length=17)
      'item_title' => string 'Item title' (length=10)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.